# Is Ron allowed to use cellotape to fix his wand?

Tags: harry-potter

My point is, if Wizards don't use regular pens, they shouldn't have access to cellotape either, do they? So, was Ron allowed to use it to fix his wand?

Comment: What does one have to do with the other?

Comment: I thik the level of "muggleness" is similar, wizards can fix things without cello tape, they use parchment instead of paper.

Comment: It wasn't sellotape, it was _spellotape_, the wizard alternative.

Comment: Also, as Hermione demonstrated, normal wands can't repair other broken wands.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzálezLópez Do quills have less "muggleness" than pens?  Also, with a name like "spellotape", it's probably magical in some way.

Comment: Ugh. Those filthy muggles and their primitive tools, can't keep em far enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It is Spellotape, not cello tape

> Ron was having far worse problems. He had patched up his wand with some borrowed **Spellotape**, but it seemed to be damaged beyond repair. It kept crackling and sparking at odd moments, and every time Ron tried to transfigure his beetle it engulfed him in thick gray smoke that smelled of rotten eggs... (CoS)

As such, it is a wizarding item, not something produced by Muggles, that means that he is both allowed to use it and has access to it.

Comment: I wonder how many places got this pun? I've heard it goes over the head of most of the North American audience, but I don't know about other European countries/Eastern audiences.

Comment: @DavidS Which pun?

Comment: @DavidS US resident here. I got it. Of course, I've watch a fair bit of British TV...

Comment: @Clockwork the cellotape/spellotape thing.